# Data visualisation: selectively animate shape but not the text in group of svg

Tags: html, svg

[image: The layout's still]

I  am working over the following [layout](https://indexmod.gq/universe) (Use Chrome to see correctly) to represent some data. I want an svg-sphere will be "breathing" but every svg-text connected to mentioned sphere will be not animated.

For now both: spheres and text are "breathing":

```
<svg height="100px" width="100px">
<defs>
<radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" 
r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
  <stop offset="0%" style="stop- 
 color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:1"/>
  <stop offset="100%" style="stop- 
 color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1"/>
 </radialGradient>
 </defs>
 <g>
 <ellipse stroke="rgb(0,{% include 
 indexmod.html %},0)" stroke-opacity="{% 
 include indexmod.html %}" stroke-width="{% 
 include stroke.html %}" cx="50" cy="50" 
 rx="10" ry="10" fill="url(#grad1)"/>
 <text x="50%" y="70%" fill="green" text- 
 anchor="middle">{% include age.html %}</text>
 <text x="50%" y="80%" fill="black" text- 
 anchor="middle">{{page.shortname}}</text>
 </g>
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" 
 type="scale" additive="sum" from="1 1" to="2 
 2" begin="0s" dur="5s" rotate="auto-reverse" 
 repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" 
 type="scale" additive="sum" from="2 2" to="1 
 1" begin="5s" dur="5s" 
 repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
 </svg>
```

Comment: apply the animation to the ellipse rather than the group then.

Comment: The question is how to apply animation to ellipse but stay in same layout — should I use  </g> tag? Or use more tags?

Comment: give the attributeTransform elements an xlink:href attribute that points to the ellipse element. You'll need therefore to give the ellipse element an id.

Comment: It help, but not correct. I gave the ellipse id="breath" and pointed with xlink:href="#breath" - after that animation works in different style and only for first svg ellipse https://indexmod.gq/universe

Comment: Your [mcve] only has one ellipse.

Comment: Dear @RobertLongson thank you for help. The main question "selectively animate shape" is done. I will re-edit and move the example of the correspondent problem to a new topic.